# Interpreting new Levene Statistic shown by SPSS

Tags: anova, levenes-test

I want to perform a between-subjects one way ANOVA on my Data. I have 4 experimental groups. I performed the tests of normality and homogeneity of variances.
The output from SPSS for homogeneity of variance is shown below:
[image]

And the output for Levene's test is shown below:

[image]

However, the Levene Statistic has 4 rows and I am not sure which one should I consider. Do the test results allow me to perform one-way ANOVA or should I go for Kruskal-Wallis H Test or Welch test?

My total sample size is 14.

I am new to stats. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply avoid the assumption of equality of variance in the first place? Then the impact of choosing a test based on a test of assumptions on the properties of your inference is avoided.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, that is also a possibility. If I avoid the assumption of equality of variances then can I represent my results using a between-subjects one way ANOVA in this case?

Comment: 1. Welch-Satterthwaite ANOVA should be okay in relation to differences in variance; on the other hand, with your design reasonably close to balanced it's probably not much of an impact in any case. 2. You have too few data points to make good within-group assessments of normality; it might be worth discussing what the response variable is and how it's measured as there may be a more suitable analysis than ANOVA

Comment: @Glen_b Okay, so basically in my data, I just want to check if there is any statistically significant difference between groups. If yes, then I want to find out which groups differ. My dependent variables are scaled variables

Comment: 1. ANOVA is not useful if you're really looking for *any* kind of difference. It only finds mean-shifts; differences in variance or distribution shapes would need other tests (one of which you did already. 2. In relation to your response variable, can you be more precise? What do you mean by "scaled variable"?

Comment: @Glen_b For my data, I have means of the different users for each of the 4 groups. I want to find out that how much the means are different from one another .i.e. if the pin is highest or fingerprint is slowest etc. Basically, you can say mean-shifts. In simple words, i want to find out that how much the mean of one group is different from the other group.

Comment: when you say "slowest" is your response variable *time*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80437/discussion-between-jishan-and-glen-b).

Comment: Yes, those are calculated timings for each user in seconds.

Comment: That should be in your question. It's important information

Comment: @Glen_b I missed it somehow

Comment: Way back when I said "discussing what the response variable is and how it's measured", I was specifically seeking this information. This will mean your data cannot be normal (don't bother testing it, you know it isn't), and that you should expect heteroscedasticity (variance should be related to the mean). A suitable model for times will probably deal with all of this. Are any of your data censored?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes these are time variables. I am so sorry. this is due to the lack of my experience in statistics. Can yopu explain what do you mean by censored?

Comment: If it took a really long time to do whatever, what would happen? Censoring is when you stop keeping track of the time before the time is actually up, and instead record whatever the time was then (and hopefully the fact that it was censored, so you know it was actually at least that long). ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)

Comment: @Glen_b I just want to know whichever group took the longest time. No, my data isn't censored - the data was recorded for the equal amount of time in all the groups.

Comment: 1. Thanks, "longest" is more precise than "different" but we will need further clarification. You'll have a distribution of times, so which will be "longest" may depend on which aspect of the distributions you want to compare across groups. One may be longer by one measure (say mean), a different one longer by a second measure (say median), and a third might be longer by yet another measure (e.g. median pairwise difference across all possible pairs). It could be that each such case is significant at some typical significance level. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... 2. Are you *only* interested in identifying the one group that took longest or are differences lower in the order important? (e.g. what if 3 groups are about equal in distribution but one took less time -- would that be important to identify)   3. Your final sentence worries me. If you're recording length of time, then you can't be recording for the same time, because length of time is the variable. Can you clarify exactly what happened? Was it possible for anything to be incomplete when you stopped timing?

Comment: 1. Thanks for your reply. Yes, by longest I mean longer by mean. 2. I am interested in identifying which group took the longest time and also the order in which the remaining groups lie i.e. the differences in the lower order are important. Actually, the recording was done for all users for exactly 24 hrs and then the recording was stopped.

Comment: You ended up with a collection of times for each user? Or only one? Are these really "amount of time in 24 hours spent doing something" and so strictly bounded below by 0 and above by 24 hours?`

Comment: Yes. The times were collected for each user. These times are basically the times each user spent using a particular application for a complete span of 24 hrs.

Comment: When you mentioned the data were times it would never have occurred to me that what you're really doing is measuring *proportion* of time. That suggests some other potential models/ analyses I'd never have considered otherwise. This is the sort of information that's important to suggesting suitable approaches. It should be in your question. ... but the same comments as before will apply -- you should expect to have heteroskedasticity and skewness in your times and you should really choose a model likely to be suitable for that.

Comment: Yes exactly. So u mean performing a one way ANOVA will probably not be a good idea?

Comment: More that something else - perhaps a more suitable (non-Gaussian) parametric model - will likely be a better idea.

Comment: Okay. I will search for the same. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: In particular I'd suggest either ignoring the upper bound and considering a generalized linear model (perhaps a gamma model), or if the longest times can get anywhere near that 24 hours upper bound (perhaps even to 16 hours, say, though it's hard to judge where to draw such a line), I'd probably be looking toward a beta regression model. If exact 0's or exact 24's (measured in hours) are possible then I'd be considering a 0-inflated model (or a 1-inflated or a 0-1 inflated model), again likely a beta regression.

Comment: Okay. So I am researching more into these models. Thanks